# how to seed encrypted password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I will be seeding my database with real people's names and email addresses, and inviting them to join the site by sending an email to the address that's in the database, with the link back to the site. If I use Devise's 'database_authenticable' with the site, it creates an email column and a column for an encrypted password. However, since I'm only seeding the database with an email, and not a password, I'm not sure if this will create problems.

Should I leave the password column blank? Should I create a dummy password and invite them to change it? Any recommendations?

When answering this question, please take note of my username on this site and provide the level of detail required for someone with my username (and others of similar intelligence) to understand your answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you using for authentication, Devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do something like this (without having to muddy around with Devise itself) is to set the password as a hidden field on your signup form and set a default value for everyone (e.g password123)

You'll need to run

```
rails g devise:views
```

To allow you to customize the devise views and change the password field as a hidden field. Then in your User model, specify what you want to set the password to, e.g

```
before_validation: set_default_password

def set_default_password
    self.password = 'password123'
    self.password_confirmation = 'password123'
end
```

Then modify the devise emails to inform the user what their password is and advise them to change it ASAP.

NOTE: This is certainly not the best solution, but it is probably the simplest to run without messing with the Devise code.

One other option you could check out is the devise_invitable gem...

https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

This allows you to send invitations to users emails, and they then set their password from there. This may not fit your exact need, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Related SO question can be found here....

[Devise: Create User without Password then Require Password to Use Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654256/devise-create-user-without-password-then-require-password-to-use-account)